# Java - How can I compare 2 sets on a custom equals/comparator without TreeSet?

Tags: java, set, equals, comparator, treeset

So I have 2 Lists of Cars

(psuedocode)

```java
Class car
private String make
private String model
private Set<String> addons
```

```
List<Car> carsMine = ... 
List<Car> carsDealers = ...
```

Currently, I want to find differences between these 2 lists based on different criteria

For example, if I want to find all Cars in `carsMine` that have the same `make` and `addons` as a car in `carsDealers`.

Currently, I'm doing

```
class MyComparator<Car> implements Comparator<Car> {
  public int compare(Car a, Car b) {
    result = a.make.compareTo(b.make)
    if (result == 0) {
       if (a.addons.size() != b.addons.size()) {
          return -1
       }
       if (!a.addons.containsAll(b.addons)) {
          return -1
       }
     return result
  }
}

TreeSet<Car> carsMineTreeSet = new TreeSet<Car>(new MyComparator<Car>);
carsMineTreeSet.addAll(carsMine)
TreeSet<Car> carsDealerTreeSet = new TreeSet<Car>(new MyComparator<Car>);
carsDealerTreeSet.addAll(carsDealers)

carsMineTreeSet.retainAll(carsDealerTreeSet);

List<Car> carsWithSameMakeAndAddons = new ArrayList<Car>(carsMineTreeSet);
```

Since I'm doing this with various other conditions, I'm creating custom comparators and repeating this.

1. Is there a way to do this with HashSets since they are O(1)? I can't override Equals since I'm doing this several times on different sets of conditions
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: 1) No. --- 2) Yes, because any valid solution is by definition better than an invalid solution, and the `Comparator` shown in the question violates the contract of `Comparator` by returning `-1` for "not equal".

Comment: @Andreas but I'm only using the comparator in this one function. So it returning -1 represents they're not equal so retainAll wont include it. Whats a better way of doing this?

Comment: I've always thought `retainAll` is based on using `equals`.  Are you sure that `Comparator` is applicable for this purpose?

Comment: @AlexRudenko TreeSet uses compare

Comment: PLFan666, have a look at Guava's [`Equivalence`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) class. By creating an `Equivalence` instead of a`Comparator` and wrapping your car objects with an `Equivalence.wrapper` you can get the desired results. Keep in mind that you may only want to convert `carsDealers` to a `HashSet`. For `carsMine` you will probably not want duplicates to be eliminated. Something like: `carsMine.stream().filter(c -> carDealers.contains(myEquiv.wrap(c)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: By the way, make sure to benchmark both solutions. While `retainAll` with the alternative solution will be `O(a)` instead of `O(a*log(b))`, and you will also be replacing two `O(n*log(n))` `addAll` operations by one `O(n)` `addAll` operation, in practice both solutions will create lots of unnecessary objects. I'm not really sure if the alternative solution will actually make things faster. Actually, for relatively small sizes of a and b you may find that a naive `O(a*b)` solution iterating both lists and comparing objects one by one may outperform the more complex implementations.

Answer (score 0):

> *if I want to find all Cars in carsMine that have the same make and addons as a car in carsDealers.*

This does not seem to work using `TreeSet` with the mentioned `MyComparator`.

For example, the car lists are as follows:

```java
List<Car> mine = Arrays.asList(
    new Car("BMW", "X5", Set.of("a", "b", "c")),
    new Car("BMW", "X6", Set.of("a", "b", "c")),
    new Car("Opel", "Astra", Set.of("a"))
    
);

List<Car> dealers = Arrays.asList(
    new Car("BMW", "X5", Set.of("a", "b", "c")),
    new Car("Audi", "Q7", Set.of("a", "b", "c")),
    new Car("BMW", "i8", Set.of("a", "b", "c"))
    
);
```

Then upon converting to `TreeSet` with the comparator which ignores `model` field, the set "loses" one of the BMW cars.

```java
TreeSet<Car> carsMineTreeSet = new TreeSet<Car>(new MyComparator());
carsMineTreeSet.addAll(mine);
System.out.println("treeset: mine: " +  carsMineTreeSet);
///////////
treeset: mine: [{make=BMW model=X5 addons=[c, b, a]}, {make=Opel model=Astra addons=[a]}]
```

So the initial purpose of *finding all cars* with matching `make` and `addons` cannot be achieved.

This may be resolved by building a set of "keys" in dealers list, and then filtering the other list:

```java
Set<String> keys = dealers.stream()
                          .map(c -> c.make + c.addons)
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<Car> cars = mine.stream()
    .filter(c -> keys.contains(c.make + c.addons))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(cars);
```

Output:

```
[{make=BMW model=X5 addons=[c, a, b]}, {make=BMW model=X6 addons=[c, a, b]}]
```

Comment: hm, I see. So itd only work if each item added to the TreeSet would be unique according to the Comparator?